# React how to update ui after every loop iteration which changes state array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on this react component. I want it to modify an array using a loop and reflect the changes in the UI after each iteration. I also added some code to halt the program so that each iteration will be displayed for a short time.

As for the UI, I have the numbers in the array itself followed by a button to start the loop. It seems that after pressing the button, the ui just freezes and the array is displayed but only after the last iteration of the loop. I want the onscreen array to change after every loop iteration. I tried using this.forceUpdate() but it did not change anything. I also tried using the spread (...) operator for changing the state but that did not change anything either. The relevant code and the GitHub are pasted below. The code can be found in src/ChangingArray.js in the project files. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ChangingArray extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: [1, 2, 3]
    }

    this.modifyArray = this.modifyArray.bind(this);
  }

  modifyArray = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      let newArray = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.state.array.length; j++) {
        newArray[j] = this.state.array[j];
      }
      newArray[i % newArray.length] = i;
      this.setState({
        array: [...newArray],
      })
      this.forceUpdate();
      //Code to halt the program
      const date = Date.now();
      let currentDate = null;
      do {
        currentDate = Date.now();
      } while (currentDate - date < 250);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.array}
        <button onClick={this.modifyArray}>modify</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

https://github.com/AntonM-248/longestPalindromicSubstringVisualizer

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
do {
        currentDate = Date.now();
      } while (currentDate - date < 250);
```

you are synchronously blocking the thread, so your UI will obviously  freeze:

I'm not sure I grasped what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to block the execution of a loop for a while before going to the next cycle, you need to implement an async iterator, let me show you how:

```
    function makeAsyncArray(arr, delay) {
    return {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
      let i = 0;
      return {
        next() {
          const done = i === arr.length;
          const value = done ? undefined : arr[i];
          i++;
          return new Promise((res) =>
            setTimeout(() => res({ value, done }), delay)
          );
        },
        return() {
          // This will be reached if the consumer called 'break' or 'return' early in the loop.
          return { done: true };
        },
      };
    },
  };
}
```

This function returns a special object called *Async Iterator* , this kind of iterators can be iterated by using this syntax:

```
 for await (const el of arr) //do something
```

Every element returned by this Iterator is a `Promise` so it can be awaited inside an `async function` and that's what we need if we want to make delayed loops that wait for something before to proceed to go on with cyclle. In this example, I used just a delay with a setTimeout to yield and block the loop asynchronously for some time, but you can use this logic to resolve that Promise with any other async logic ( for example the result of a fetch request ).

This is a working React implementation of this logic:

```
const arr = makeAsyncArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10], 1000);

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  // Data array will be populated adding one element every 1000ms since we have initialized the async iterator to resolve after 1000ms
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      for await (const el of arr) {
        setData((d) => [...d, el]);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}


function makeAsyncArray(arr, delay) {
  return {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
      let i = 0;
      return {
        next() {
          const done = i === arr.length - 1;
          const value = done ? undefined : arr[i];
          i++;
          return new Promise((res) =>
            setTimeout(() => res({ value, done }), delay)
          );
        },
        return() {
          // This will be reached if the consumer called 'break' or 'return' early in the loop.
          return { done: true };
        },
      };
    },
  };
}
```

The ***live demo***: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yie8pg